# Wordpress: Add extra fee in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a webshop in Woocommerce (wordpress). It's a wine shop and I need to add an extra cost: 0,08 euro per bottle (product).

I've found this and adjusted it, but I cannot get the number of products (bottles) to multiply with 0.08 euro.
In the cart I do get an extra line but the value is 0.

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function get_cart_contents_count() {
     return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count', $this->cart_contents_count );
}


function woo_add_cart_fee() {

  global $woocommerce;

  $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Custom', 'woocommerce'), $get_cart_contents_count * 0.08 );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

Comment: `$get_cart_contents_count` is an undefined variable, which PHP will politely treat as `0`. perhaps you wanted `get_cart_contents_count()` (i.e.: a function call) instead.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but when I try this, the page does not load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your functions.php but it will be applied on over all cart

```
// Hook before adding fees 
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');

function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
    $fees = 0.08;
    $cart->add_fee( 'Handling fee', $fees);
}
```

**EDIT:**
**To multiply it with each product do something like**

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');
function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
    $fees = 0;

    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $item ){
       $fees += $item[ 'quantity' ] * 0.08; 
    }

    if( $fees != 0 ){
        $cart->add_fee( 'Handling fee', $fees);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Omer, but how do i multiply this with the quantity of products in the cart?

Comment: Yes, We're getting closer. This codes multiplies the fee per product, but I need to multiply it with the quantity of products (number/pieces).
Now I have 2 different products in my cart and it gives me a fee for 0.16 euro which is already something.
but from each product I have 5 pieces, so I should get a fee of 0.80 euro. Can this be done?

Comment: Inside the foreach loop multiple 0,08 by $item[ 'quantity' ], checkout the edit

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about adding surcharge to the cart. You can get all the related information from the [Woocommerce Doc in here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/).