# How to count custom field as extra fees in WooCommerce cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a issue about counting in WooCommerce's cart.
I'd like to add a Handing fees field to each products and dramatically count total of fees in cart.
According my research, I've created a field in my products.
[Demo-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajvW7.png)

My next step is to count this field in my cart.
I've also searched this issue in Google, but I could only find some solutions([Wordpress: Add extra fee in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100694/wordpress-add-extra-fee-in-cart)) to count a fixed fee rather than a dramatic function.
[Demo-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1qnu.png)

```
// Display Fields
  add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data',      'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

  // Save Fields
  add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

  function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

    global $woocommerce, $post;

    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    // Custom fields will be created here...

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
        'id'                => '_number_field', 
        'label'             => __( 'Environmental fee', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder'       => '', 
        'description'       => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'              => 'number', 
        'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step'  => 'any',
                'min'   => '0'
            ) 
    )
  );

    echo '</div>';

  }


  function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){


    // Number Field
    $woocommerce_number_field = $_POST['_number_field'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_number_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_number_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_number_field ) );


  }


  add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','endo_handling_fee' );
  function endo_handling_fee() {
       global $woocommerce;

       if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
            return;

       $fee = 5.00;
       $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Handling', $fee, true, 'standard' );
  }
```

How can modify function to count each products' fee, which value is provided from custom field I created, in the subtotal column?

Now, I'm trying the following code.
I believe the key is how to grab the value of products and make the value as a variable.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');
function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
$fees = 0;

foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $item ){
   $fees += $item[ 'quantity' ] * 0.08; 
}

if( $fees != 0 ){
    $cart->add_fee( 'Handling fee', $fees);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you need is get_post_meta to grab the value of your custom field.

```
$prod_fee = get_post_meta($item['product_id'] , '_number_field', true);
```

Then you can accumulate this and show it as a consolidated fee.

Comment: Hi Anfelipe,
Thanks for replying,
I've tried your example.

it doesn't work and It seems not get the value from the product.

$prod_fee = get_post_meta($item['product_id'] , '_number_field', true);





$prod_fee = 5;
//this example works..

Comment: How did you implement the solution?
The answer of @Mitul is wrong, because $item['product_id'] is out of the scope of the foreach, put the $prod_fee WITHIN the foreach block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the product fees from the meta data of the product as @Anfelipe gives the code

`$prod_fee = get_post_meta($item['product_id'] , '_number_field', true);`

After that you need to add condition or do calculation in.

```
function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
    $fees = 0;
    $prod_fee = get_post_meta($item['product_id'] , '_number_field', true);
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $item ){
       $fees += $item[ 'quantity' ] * $prod_fee ; 
    }
    if( $fees != 0 ){
        $cart->add_fee( 'Handling fee', $fees);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mitul,
Thanks for replying.
I've added your example to my project.
But it's not thing happen in my cart of subtotal column.
I also try to use another field, such as "_sale_price", to be variable.
The result is the same.
Could you probably know where is wrong?

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Mitul, Thanks for your example. It inspire me to reach the function I want.